# How SQLMAP fetches tables, columns from the database?

Tags: python, sql, security, cracking, sqlmap

I have understood that how SQLMAP checks for vulnerabilities but now i'm fascinated about how after getting the vulnerability SQLMAP fetches the databases, tables, columns. I tried to understand by looking on their github repo but still.

Comment: anyone there to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of [this Hakipedia page](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/SQL_Injection#INFORMATION_SCHEMA) on SQLi regarding how the MySQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table is queried in order to fetch database metadata.

> The MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA database (available from MySQL 5), is made up of table-like objects (aka, system views), that result in the exposure of metadata in a relational format. The execution of arbitrary injections via SELECT statements are thus possible to retrieve or to format said metadata. Metadata is only accessible to an attacker if the objects retrieved are accessible by the current user account. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database is automatically created by the server upon MySQL installation, and the metadata within is maintained by the server.

For example, a `UNION` command could be injected into the SQL command to retrieve data from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.